# Compare directory with sub-folders

Tags: powershell, compare, directory

I have been have a tough time with this but I am trying to do a compare between two servers and have them compare all of the files from one server to the other. Even inside the subfolders. So far I've gotten it to compare the folder names and files but can't get it to go inside the folders and compare the contents. Here's a few things I've tried.

```
$A = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $Path
$B = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $PAth1
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $A -DifferenceObject $B -PassThru
```

This is what I started with and it works the best but still doesn't go inside the sub-folders. I also tried to use foreach statements with Arrays to store the content in an array and compare the arrays but this doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
$FileDirectoryA = "Path"
$FileDirectoryC = "path"
$A = foreach($folderA in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectoryA)
{
    $FolderA
}
$B = foreach($FileA in Get-ChildItem $ArrayA)
{
    $FileA
}
$C = foreach($folderC in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectoryC)
{
    $FolderC
}
$D = foreach($FileC in Get-ChildItem $ArrayC)
{
    $FileC
}

Compare-Object $B $D
```

When I try and just do a

```
Compare-Object $Path $Path2
```

It errors on all of the folders saying permission denied which doesn't make much sense to me.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you specify the property to compare :

```
$a = ls c:\temp\ -rec
$b = icm -computername $servername -scriptblock{ls c:\temp\ -rec}
compare $a $b -Property fullname
```

A more reliable way might be to use robocopy 
`robocopy.exe \\serverA\Folder1 \\serverB\Folder2 /e /l /log:c:\temp\dif.txt`

Comment: When I do this it reads out everything in the files and says that is all has differences, when only a few files really have differences

Comment: this will work only if you compare directories with a same root (ie c:\temp on both local and remote server), otherwise fullname will be different

Comment: Well I'm comparing a server to a server, not local

Comment: @Andrew I think you got the idea ...  cant compare \\servera\c$\temp with \\serverb\c$\another dir -> full name will never match !

Comment: The full name of the path will always be different because the Servername will be different

Comment: @Andrew nope, if you make the dir listing remotly using invoke-command for example (as in my code above). I've updated my answer to suggest another way

Answer (score 1):

I think this powershell script https://github.com/oflisback/dirdiff addresses your problem, it scans two directories and reports differences:

```html
PS C:\> dirdiff.ps1 C:\dir1 C:\dir2
One identical file:
        .\identical.txt
One file only present in C:\dir1:
        .\newdir1.txt
2 files only present in C:\dir2:
        .\newdir2.txt
        .\newdir\newfilesdir2.txt
One file present in both directories and has different content:
        .\modified.bin
```

The script is based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cchamberlain/883959151aa1162e73f1) so credit to [cchamberlein](https://gist.github.com/cchamberlain).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a reasonable comparison I think.  You can use regex on the return values to rebuild the original filepaths if you so desire.

```
$Dir1="C:\Test"
$Dir2="C:\Test2"
$A=(Get-ChildItem $Dir1 -Recurse).VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir1),""
$B=(Get-ChildItem $Dir2 -Recurse).VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir2),""
Compare-Object $A $B
```

This reuslts in an output like...

```
InputObject                                                        SideIndicator                                                     
-----------                                                        -------------                                                     
\New folder\temp.txt                                               =>                                                                
\temp.txt                                                          <=                                                                
\New folder\New folder\temp.txt                                    <=
```

**Update**

I think should do everything you are looking for.  You'll need to change the `$Dir1` and `$Dir2` values.  It's likely over-complicated but it does appear to work.

```
$Dir1="C:\Test"
$Dir2="C:\Test2"
$Items1=Get-ChildItem $Dir1 -Recurse
$Items2=Get-ChildItem $Dir2 -Recurse
$A=$Items1.VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir1),""
$B=$Items2.VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir2),""
$Exist_Diff=Compare-Object $A $B

$Exist_Diff | %{
    $Current_Item=$_.InputObject
    if($_.SideIdicator -eq "<="){
        Write-Host "No file equivilent to $Dir1$Current_Item found in $Dir2"
        }else{
        Write-Host "No file equivilent to $Dir2$Current_Item found in $Dir1"
        }
    }

$Items1 | %{
    if ($Exist_Diff.InputObject -notcontains ($_.VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir1),""))
        {
        $MatchingFile=[string]$_.VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir1),$Dir2      
        try{if(Test-Path $MatchingFile)
            {
            if((Get-Item $MatchingFile).length -gt $_.Length)
                {
                Write-host $_.fullname "is larger than" $MatchingFile
                }
            }}catch{}
        }
    }
$Items2 | %{
    if ($Exist_Diff.InputObject -notcontains ($_.VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir1),""))
        {
        $MatchingFile=[string]$_.VersionInfo.Filename -replace [regex]::Escape($Dir2),$Dir1      
        try{if(Test-Path $MatchingFile)
            {
            if((Get-Item $MatchingFile).length -gt $_.Length)
                {
                Write-host $_.fullname  "is larger than" $MatchingFile
                }
            }}catch{}
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only found one difference that was outside the subfolders, the compare still isn't looking in and comparing files in the folders

thanks

Comment: That is not the result I experience.  I am seeing results on files that exist in one area but not the other from first directory on down to the third layer.  I will add the results I get in my answer.

Comment: When I run it, it finds one difference. which is a file that is on one server but not the other. When I run beyond compare there are some difference on about 3-4 different configs inside a folder that this is not picking up

Comment: The method will only find if a file exists in one directory but not another.  Are you looking to find differences in the content of the files?  If so, are you looking to have those differences enumerated or just to know that there is a difference?

Comment: I need to check the content for differences and I just need to know if there is a difference.

Comment: Are you looking to find if the file exists in one place but not the other as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | ForEach-Object{

   $Dest = Join-Path $Destination $_.FullName.Substring($Source.Length)

   $bool = Test-Path $Dest

   if(!$bool){
       #Write of some thing here to indicate difference
   }

}
```

Comment: This looks like it is looking to compare file names. I need it to compare the content aswell. Thanks

Comment: Yes but it will find all files. You can then add your compare logic.